# expected unqualified-id before '[' token c++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm trying to make a tokenizer function, but I'm getting an annoying error. I am new to c++ and am not up to par with the syntax. Thanks for any help you can give me.

```
using namespace std;

string[] tokenizer(const string &str, const char &delim){
    string tokens[3];
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) tokens[i] = "";
    int start = 0;
    int toks = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
        if (str[i] == delim){
            for(int j = start; j < i; j++)
                tokens[toks] += str[i];
        }
    }
    return tokens;
}
```

The error is in the function header.

```
expected unqualified-id before '[' token
```

Sorry for all those careless errors. I fixed them but I still get the same error.

Comment: Use a `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: Wrap `str[i] == delim` in parentheses.

Comment: So many things wrong... What does it mean for a function to return `string[]`? What's `toks`? And what is `return toks[]` supposed to do?

Comment: returning toks is supposed to return the memory address of an array. I want to be able to type in 3 words separated by spaces and store the 3 words in an array.

Comment: you can't return `toks[]` since (a) `toks` isn't a variable (as far as we know) and (b) the syntax `toks[]` is meaningless in the context of a return. I assume you're coming from Java and/or C#. C++ works a little differently. Check out my answer for a working implementation that supports any number of words (aka tokens).

Comment: sorry sorry, yet another careless error. I fixed it now. Still getting the same error

Comment: Now your problem is that you cannot have your function return `string[]` - the syntax is invalid. Just use the implementation I show below, and you'll be happy :)

Comment: ahhhhh okay I get it. Can't I also just point to the address of the array and pass by reference?

Comment: Like [zombo.com](http://www.zombo.com) says, you can do *anything at all*. But why play around with pointers, which can cause subtle bugs/issues and not just use `std::vector`?

Answer (score 1):

Where are parentheses ?!

`if str[i] == delim{` to `if (str[i] == delim){`

And

`tokens[i] == ""` to `tokens[i] = ""`

And

`return toks[];` to `return toks;`

Answer (score 1):

The signature of your function

```
string[] tokenizer(const string &str, const char &delim)
```

is not valid C++. The typical way to do this is with `std::vector<>`:

```
std::vector<string> tokenizer(const string &str, const char &delim)
```

Then:

```
string tokens[3];
```

Forget this right now. What does `3` even mean? Why don't you fence the indexing into `tokens`? Code like that is the root of all evil and bad sayings about C and C++. Use `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<string> tokens;
```

To add items to a `std:vector`, use either `push_back()` or `emplace_back()`.

Then, the idiomatic way to iterate over items in C++ is to use iterators or range-based for:

```
for(auto it = str.begin(), end = str.end(); it!=end; ++it)
```

or ...

```
for(auto c : str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is weird (I assume you are coming from Java or C#) and there's a lot of context missing, but I assume your goal is to take a string and "tokenize" it. Here's a working implementation, roughly based on your code. It's not *optimal* by any means, but it works and you should be able understand it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> tokenizer(const std::string &str,
                                   char delim = ' ',
                                   bool emptyok = false)
{
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    std::string t;

    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) 
    {       
        if (str[i] == delim) 
        {
            if(emptyok || (t.length() != 0)) 
                tokens.push_back(t);

            t.clear();      
            continue;
        }

        t.push_back(str[i]);
    }

    // And take care of anything that's left over...
    if(emptyok || (t.length() != 0)) 
        tokens.push_back(t);

    return tokens;
}

int main(int, char **)
{       
    std::string s = "This is a test of the emergency broadcast system yo!";

    std::vector<std::string> x = tokenizer(s, ' ');

    for(int i = 0; i != x.size(); i++)
        std::cout << "Token #" << i << ": \"" << x[i] << "\"" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you not allowed to return an array in c++?

Comment: Not like that, no. You can return a *pointer*, but then you must dynamically allocate the memory using `new` since you cannot return stack-based temporaries. Just make your life easier and use `std::vector`.

Comment: This crashes my code with the WIEIDEST error I've ever seen. It prints random characters and directories and it's just so weird.

Comment: This *exact* code? Or code that you tweaked? If so, we'll need to see the tweaked code.

Comment: exact code, I took away the std:: everywhere because I said using namespace std. This is how I called it vector<string> inputV = tokenizer(input,' ',false); By the way I also changed the header by getting rid of =' ' and = false

Comment: So, how do you display the contents of `inputV`? Dollars to donuts you're mishandling that.